# How to change CFLAGS option -march from native to corei7?

Tags: gentoo, gcc

Is it possible to change the `CFLAGS` `-march=native` to `-march=corei7`? Would I have to recompile the whole system once this change is made?

I would like to setup `distcc` and I read that `march` cannot be set to `native`.

Comment: And what `native` flag selected so far in gcc? You can check that with `gcc -march=native -E -v - </dev/null 2>&1 | grep cc1`

Comment: /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/cc1 -E -quiet -v - -march=corei7-avx -mcx16 -msahf -mno-movbe -maes -mpclmul -mpopcnt -mno-abm -mno-lwp -mno-fma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mno-bmi -mno-bmi2 -mno-tbm -mavx -mno-avx2 -msse4.2 -msse4.1 -mno-lzcnt -mno-rdrnd -mno-f16c -mno-fsgsbase --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=8192 -mtune=corei7-avx

Comment: So you are perfectly fine. As you can see `gcc` just automatically translated `native` to `corei7`.

Comment: To extend what @jimmij said, executables compiled on your *current* machine with `-march=native` will be fine on your *current* machine. If you want to build or run on other machines, you do need to change your flags.

Comment: If you do need to rebuild everything `emerge -e @world @system` ... I forget if `@system` is implicit in `@world` or not.

Comment: Yes, `system` is a subset of `world`.

Comment: How do I tell if I actually need to rebuild anything? When I change USE flags I can do something like "emerge --update --newuse @world" and know for sure things need rebuilt. Is there something similar for changing march?

Comment: See [Safe CFLAGS](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Safe_CFLAGS), and remember `--emptytree` or `-e` is the master set.  I.E. `--newuse` or `-N` is irrelevant.